# Why SIGSTKSZ is often mutiplied by 4?

Tags: c, unix, signals

I've noticed that a lot of repositories do not use just SIGSTKSZ as alternative signal stack size but multiply it by 4. Examples:

Code from [here](http://web.mit.edu/svn/src/swig-1.3.25/Tools/WAD/Wad/signal.c):

```
#define STACK_SIZE 4*SIGSTKSZ
char wad_sig_stack[STACK_SIZE];
```

And from [here](https://github.com/doctest/doctest/blob/a384864346f48c7ff5608051c176e7bd505712ae/doctest/doctest.h#L4524):

```
size_t FatalConditionHandler::altStackSize = 4 * SIGSTKSZ;
```

But `man` tells: *The value SIGSTKSZ is defined to be the number of bytes/chars that would be used to cover the usual case when allocating an alternate stack area.*

So why the most common alternative signal stack size is `4 * SIGSTKSZ`?

Comment: https://github.com/doctest/doctest/issues/129